# Removing element from ArrayList if contains value

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList that's populated with sentences but need certain elements to be removed based on if they contain a certain integer.

Here's what my ArrayList looks like

```
[Savings 12345678 0.60, Checking 98765432 0.01, Deposit 98765432 300, Transfer 98765432 12345678 300]
```

I want to remove elements that include ***98765432***

(`Checking 98765432 0.01`, `Deposit 98765432 300`, and `Transfer 98765432 12345678 300`)

but keep `Savings 12345678 0.60`.

Comment: Post your code. What is the ArrayList of?

Comment: [Filtering a list in Java](https://zetcode.com/java/filterlist/) - I'd recommend scrolling down to the "Filtering a list with Java 8 streams" section

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Streams' Filter method to filter the List using a `Predicate`.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-filter-java-examples/

Quick Example: `list = list.stream().filter(num -> !(num + "").contains("98765432"));`

Comment: Can you please little more information, like syntax etc. So it could better to understand beginner at same place

Answer (score 0):

Perform a regular loop inside each element from the ArrayList.Then use the .contain function to search for a specific value at each element in the ArrayList(in your case a specific number:98765432).Finally over-write that element with a new string startIndex and endIndex.